# Retrieving value from Listbox Item

Tags: c#

I have a problem getting back a values of a Listbox item.
The listbox is populated with a custom class element that i made.

```
private void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem(
            int.Parse(txtId1.Text),
            txtName1.Text,
            int.Parse(txtMinLevel1.Text),
            int.Parse(txtMinAttr11.Text),
            int.Parse(txtMinAttr21.Text),
            float.Parse(txtDamage1.Text),
            float.Parse(txtAdditionalDmg1.Text),
            cmbAdditionalDmgType1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
            float.Parse(txtRange1.Text),
            float.Parse(txtCost1.Text)
            );
        list1.Add(li);

        lstWeapons1.DataSource = null;
        lstWeapons1.DataSource = list1;
        lstWeapons1.DisplayMember = "name";
        lstWeapons1.ValueMember = "id";
    }

    private void lstWeapons1_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = lstWeapons1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

After the event `text` value is ListItem not the value I expect

Comment: Not knowing the cusotom class we can only guess. Cast the Item to the class and then pick the value you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case every element of the Listbox is an instance of your custom class `ListItem`. Calling ToString() on this custom class is useless if you don't have defined an override of the ToString() method in your custom class. So you have these choices

```
private void lstWeapons1_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstWeapons1.SelectedValue != null) 
       var text = lstWeapons1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

or

```
private void lstWeapons1_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstWeapons1.SelectedItem != null) 
    {
       ListItem item = lstWeapons1.SelectedItem as ListItem;
       var text = item.id.ToString();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ListItem
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.id.ToString();
    }
}

private void lstWeapons1_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstWeapons1.SelectedItem != null) 
    {
       var text = lstWeapons1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Notice that I always check if the SelectedItem or SelectedValue are null because you can't rule out the possibility that SelectedIndexChanged will be called when there is no item selected

Comment: The first choice doesnt work. It return "ListItem" but the second one work like a charm.
Many thanks